# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied - ftplib

Tags: python, ftplib

I am trying to download files from a ftp server but I am running into an error permission denied error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/x34/Documents/Python/ftp_download.py", line 27, in <module>
     download()
   File "/Users/x34/Documents/Python/ftp_download.py", line 21, in download
     with open(filename,'wb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/p012r018_5dt19900722_z20_30.tif.gz'
```

Downloading manually or with filezilla works fine but my script below does not

```
from ftplib import ftp    
ftp = FTP(r'ftp.glcf.umd.edu')
ftp.login()

directory = 'glcf/Landsat/WRS2/p012/r018/p012r018_5dx19900722.TM-GLS1990'
filename = '/p012r018_5dt19900722_z20_30.tif.gz'

ftp.cwd(directory)

with open(filename,'wb') as f:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR' + filename,f.write)

ftp.close()
```

One another note... and perhaps I misread the docs - http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html but I do not fully understand where ftplib decides to download the files (default download directory?). Is there another module better suited for this application?

**UPDATE**

I should clarify that the filename on the server does not contain the '/' in front. I simply added that as it appeared to help locate the correct file location and name as prior attempts ended in the following error 
     ftplib.error_perm: 500 Unknown command.

the full path to the file is

```
 ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/Landsat/WRS2/p012/r018/p012r018_5dx19900722.TM-GLS1990/p012r018_5dt19900722_z20_30.tif.gz'
```

Comment: It looks like your script is trying to save the downloaded content to a file at the root (`/`) of your filesystem. Do you have enough permissions there?

It is trying to save the file with the original filename, and it is preceded by a `/`, thus creating the file at `/`.

Comment: the main reason to add the / in front was that it seemed like a step forward because before it was giving me another error this being the last part of that traceback --> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 219, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 500 Unknown command.

Comment: Try adding a space character after "REPR" in your code. I've updated the  code in the answer. You are concatenating "REPR" with the filename, but the correct would be: "REPR file.txt"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its saves your file where you ask it to save, in the line `with open(filename,'wb') as f:`, you are opening the file to save the received content.

And, as your filename starts with a `/`, it tries to save to the root (`/`) of your filesystem, where it looks like you don't have enough permissions.

Try this:

```
from ftplib import ftp    
ftp = FTP(r'ftp.glcf.umd.edu')
ftp.login()

directory = 'glcf/Landsat/WRS2/p012/r018/p012r018_5dx19900722.TM-GLS1990'
filename = '/p012r018_5dt19900722_z20_30.tif.gz'

ftp.cwd(directory)

with open(filename[1:],'wb') as f: # slices the string, "cutting" out the "/"
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename,f.write)

ftp.close()
```

Notice that we changed the filename to be written in your filesystem (line `with open(filename[1:],'wb') as f:`). Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation), if you don't know the slice operator.

Also, you should put a space character in the end of the `'RETR'` string in your code. It should be `'RETR ' + filename` instead of `'RETR' + filename`. '`RETR somefile.txt`' is a command to the FTP server, and you were doing '`RETRsomefile.txt`', corrupting the command with the filename.

Comment: I tried your suggestions on both my pc and mac but to no avail as it gives me the error of "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 219, in getresp raise error_perm, resp ftplib.error_perm: 500 Unknown command  ------    the ftp site is free to the public if anyone wants to try if its only my computers?

Comment: After correcting the code with the space at the end of 'RETR ', I am getting a permission error at the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same filename variable in two places where I assume the root "/" is valid for your ftp but obviously a permission issue locally.

Try using "/" in the ftp command, but without "/" on the local file you are opening